# Как сохранять данные, введённые пользователем в input-форму на сайте?

Tags: javascript, php, python, backend

Есть сайт. На сайте есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую я хочу, чтобы пользователь вводил своё имя и номер и эти данные отправлялись мне и я человеку перезванивал.
Как это сделать? С фронтендом я знаком, но бэкенд не изучал.
Что нужно сделать для сохранения данных?
Какой язык порекомендуете, чтобы написать код? (можно ли это сделать на питоне или JS, так как я с ними знаком?)
Как вообще это работает?
Есть знающие люди?

Comment: mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);echo "The email message was sent.";

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ага, вам потребовалось что-то больше визиток, и теперь вы хотите написать бэкенд.

В принципе, языков для бэка много, сходу могу сказать про `JS`, `PHP`, `Python`, `Ruby`, `Java`,`C#`,`Go`. Последние три, скорее, не для сайтов, а для больших веб-приложений, но мало ли, некоторые и на хаскеле сайты пишут :)

Про руби я знаю мало, так что расскажу про первые три.

`PHP` - легче всего встраивается в готовую визитку, если вам ничего не надо кроме данной функции, то можете воспользоваться им. Если решите учить его, то, скорее всего, придётся учить `Laravel`.

`Python` - если бэк, то, скорее всего, это будет `Django`. Лично я на нём и пишу, хороший язык, отличная документация ко всему, что есть. Но порог вхождения несколько выше, чем в php.

`JS` - скорее всего, `Express`. Неплохой выбор, особенно, если вы знаете js.

Что вы выберете - зависит только от вас, гугл в помощь. То, что вам требуется (сохранить данные и отправить сообщение) можно сделать в любом из инструментов, опять же гугл в помощь, это одно из самого первого, что требуется сделать, информации по проблеме очень много. В общем, вам надо решить, на чём вы будете делать бэк, а затем делать (и задавать конкретные вопросы).

Answer (score 3):

Можно на `php` это быстро сделать используя обычную `html` форму (В коде могут быть ошибки и не обработаны данные в плане безопасности)

```html
<form action="/path_to_send.php" method="post">
  <p><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name"></p>
  <p><input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Yout phone"></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
</form>
```

В аттрибуте `action` пишете путь к файлу обработчика. А в этом файле уже принимаете и обрабатываете ваши `post` запросы, к примеру простая отправка на почту (можно эти данные записать в БД, или в файл):

```
<?php
$name  = $_POST['name']; // from input name
$phone = $_POST['phone']; // from input name
// Need security data
$msg   = "Username: {$name}<br>";
$msg   = "Phone: {$phone}<br>";

mail('your_email@mail.ru', 'User submitted the form', $msg); // send to mail, need check
```

Как вариант ещё легкое и быстрое решение создать телеграмм бота и после отправки данных с форм увидите в Вашей телеграмм группе с ботом.

Answer (score 2):

> Как это сделать?
> Что нужно сделать для сохранения данных?

Очень много статей на эту тему. Попробуйте поискать.

> Какой язык порекомендуете, чтобы написать код?

Выбирать только вам. Каждому своё. Стоит только начать.

> можно ли это сделать на питоне или JS

Можно, и на python, и на js.

> Как вообще это работает?

Алгоритм такой: frontend отправляет запрос на сервер с данными. Сервер обрабатывает их(сохраняет в бд, отправляет данные на e-mail и т.д.) и возвращает на frontend ответ, что все хорошо (или плохо). Frontend реагирует на ответ.